# zipkin added to spring boot app cause failure to startup Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, zipkin

**spring-boot 2.3.4-RELEASE**

Error is shown after adding the zipkin dependencies to a project and running with

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Cannot figure out the error causing it. Other spring-boot apps in the project are running fine with the same zipkin configs and application.yaml.  Any help to figure out how to debug this would be helpful.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.ZipkinBackwardsCompatibilityAutoConfiguration$BackwardsCompatibilityConfiguration
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]

pom.xml

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Hoxton.SR10</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

dependencies section sample of two zipkin/sleuth dependencies

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: Test App
  sleuth:
    sampler:
      probability: 0.5
    trace-id128: true
    web:
      additional-skip-pattern: ".*/actuator.*"
  zipkin:
    enabled: true
    base-url: http://${ZIPKIN_HOST:zipkin}/
    service:
      name: ${spring.application.name}
    discovery-client-enabled: false
    sender:
      type: web
```